# Use a remote json file with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How would I use a remote url like http://example.com/file.json insead of a local file

```
$.get("file.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function(){
        $("body").append("Name: " + this.title);
    });
}, "json");
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to access a remote file

Comment: you probably need cors or a callback...

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("file.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function(){
        $("body").append("Name: " + this.title);
    });
}, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over the data array you can use the jQuery each method.
As an optimization, I would recommend writing all of the html to a variable first and accessing the DOM via appendTo only once the loop has finished. Try this:

```
var content = '';
jQuery.get('file.json', function(data){
var posts = data.posts;//assumse the posts property of the returned object is the data     array you want to iterate over
jQuery.each(posts, function(index, item){
        content += item.title + '<br/>;' //build html string here
});
//Only attempt to insert if there is something to insert
if (content) {
    content.appendTo('body);
    /**
    * You could also use vanilla JS here for this step
    * ie: document.body.innerHTML = content;
    **/
}
```

});

Comment: I want to use a remote file, can you help?

Comment: You place the url in the get method as the first parameter (where 'file.json' is).